# Examples of continuous but not uniformly continuous functions on various domains

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

What would be some simple examples of functions that are continuous but not uniformly continuous on the following intervals?

1. $D=\mathbb R$
2. $D=(0,1]$
3. $D=[0,1]$

This is what I came up with:

1. $f(x)=1/\sin(x)$
2. $f(x)=1/x$
3. $f(x)=?$

Are these correct? Could it be that the third case is impossible? If so, why?

Thanks to anyone for the help!!

Comment: In the first example, what is $f(0)$?

Comment: Did you try $\sqrt x$?

Comment: Or even $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: For the 3rd case, are you aware that all continuous functions on compact spaces are uniformly continuous?

Comment: Case 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem

Comment: Replace the first example with [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1614496/386889) for instance. Your second example [is fine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381389), and so is your intuition about [the 3rd question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361602).

Comment: Would it matter if for the first one I take f(x)=x^2 or f(x)=x^n?

Comment: @AnneBauval And for the third to summarize: it is impossible because any function would be compact which is a finiteness property.  So for uniformly continuous functions one particular delta works for every x and similarly compact functions have finitely many delta, which are enough to describe the whole space?

Comment: I don't know what a compact function is, but you seem to have the right ideas to prove the Heine-Cantor theorem (a proof can be found in every textbook on Topology, and in [several posts on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Heine-Cantor)).

Comment: "Would it matter if for the first one I take f(x)=x^2 or f(x)=x^n? ": please look at the answer in the first link provided just before that comment of yours.